# Filtering array of objects in svelte typescript

Tags: typescript, svelte, svelte-transition

I want to check whether a certain username is in the array of user objects.

I am fetching voter list with fastapi. A user has username value like `{"username": "mickey"}`. I am storing the current user with persistent_storage as `$username`.

```
<script>
let question = {answers:[], voter:[], content: ''}

function get_question() {
     fastapi("get", "/api/question/detail/" + question_id, {}, (json) => {         
     question = json
 })}
</script>

{#if question.voter.forEach(v => v.username).includes($username) }
```

However, `question.voter.username.forEach(v => v.username)` keeps returning undefined.
I am kinda confused between the nature of python and javascript.

Or is my approach wrong? Should I create another fast API call?

Comment: forEach does not return anything, if you want to filter a collection you could use this `.filter` instead

`question.voter.filter(v => v.username.includes($username))`

Comment: @aleEspinosaM `question.voter.filter(v => v.username.includes($username))` this is still returning undefined? Why is it not returning false value?

Comment: filter returns an array not a boolean value, if you want to check if returns a boolean value, you could indexOf, every, some ..etc

you can take a look at the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter,

and this example in svelte to know how to filter https://svelte.dev/repl/a138b0c8579b4fc8bdde842a9d922b1f?version=3.17.1

Comment: @aleEspinosaM I have settled on `{#if question.voter.filter(v => v.username.includes($username)).length == 1}` for now. But isn't there a cleaner way to do this? Like in python we would filter with `if username in [v.username for v in question.voter]`.

Comment: *I am storing the current user with persistent_storage as $username.* Is the value of  `$username` an object or a string?

Comment: In case `$username` is a string value (what one would expect) the check could be `{#if question.voter.some(v => v.username === $username)}`

Comment: @Corrl: That is the answer I would have posted, why don't you add it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$username` holds a string value the check could be

```
{#if question.voter.some(v => v.username === $username)}
```

Also possible would be

```
{#if question.voter.map(v => v.username).includes($username)}
```

but I think `.some()` is besides being shorter also more efficient because it only iterates the array once and stops as soon as a result is found

Notice that your current solution mentioned in the comments using [String.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes?retiredLocale=de)

```
{#if question.voter.filter(v => v.username.includes($username)).length == 1}
```

is error prone because this will match longer usernames containing the current username. Like when there's a user object `{username: 'foobar'}` and `$username = 'foo'` this will match when there's no `{username: foo}`. Could be adjusted to

```
{#if question.voter.filter(v => v.username === $username).length == 1}
```

but compared that's not the preferred option

Comment: 'some' function in javascript is like 'any' function in python?

Comment: @Maeror *The **any()** function returns **True** if any item in an **iterable** are true, otherwise it returns **False*** -> `any(iterable)` on the other hand *The **some()** method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided **function*** -> `some(callbackFn)` + *It should return a **truthy** to indicate the element passes the test, and a **falsy** value otherwise.* - true != truthy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy?retiredLocale=de) - a function is called *'on its own'*, a method is called on  an object, here Array.some()

Comment: @Maeror MDN is a good resource to look up things https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?retiredLocale=de